# Obtain access token for a keycloak user using REST API

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, keycloak-services

If I am provided with a valid userId in the backend, I want to obtain a valid session inside Keycloak for that user and bypass the manual authetication process -> redirecting directly to the home page of the web app.

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds dangerous but you need to create a custom Authentication flow and only have the `Username Validation` execution

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_authentication-flows